# Run VMware Player with no GUI(Headless) by editing .vmx file

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player

I used to run VMware Player with no GUI by editing the .vmx file and disabling a preference to confirm before closing a virtual machine.  The process was to disable that option in VMware Player preferences by adding two lines to the end of the .vmx file.

This will make closing VMware Player send the VM to background and close the Player GUI.

I searched the Internet to find out what those two lines were but have had no luck; all the posts just talk about using `vmrun` command or using VMware Server.

---

Edit 1

Headless is the terminology for the service not without GUI

---

Does any one know what those two lines are?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "no GUI"?  How did you close VMware Player without a GUI?

Comment: Colse the vmware screen but not shutting down the OS

Comment: That doesn't explain exactly what "no GUI" means to you.  What do you expect to see (and not see)?  Do you still want a window with the guest screen?  Do you still want a titlebar with minimize/maximize/close buttons?  Are you just looking to hide the VMware Player menubar and toolbar?

Comment: No I don't want the guest screen,it sort of un link the process from the player window and close it but the guest remains running

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The terminology you're looking for is to run *VMs* (not VMware Player, which is actually a UI to interact with the VM) *headless*.

Close all VMware Workstation and Player instances and try editing your preferences file (`%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\VMware\preferences.ini` on Windows, `~/.vmware/preferences` on Linux) to add the lines:

```
pref.vmplayer.exit.vmAction = "disconnect"
pref.vmplayer.confirmOnExit = "FALSE"
```

Comment: this will make any instance of VMs headless there is an alternative code to be added to .vmx file to make only one VM headless maybe pref.exit.vmAction = "disconnect" or exit.vmAction = "disconnect" I tried them but did not work any way this is good for now thanks

Comment: No, there is no way to do this on a per-VM basis.  The preferences file affects the UI behavior; the `.vmx` files affect VM behaviors.

Comment: Just to add, after doing this and launching a VM, it is safe to click the X and close your VM console window. It will continue to run in the background and not crash. Your sanity is secure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look for the VMware VIX API.  You will need to create a login to download it but it is free. It installs a tool called 'vmrun' that you can use to start the VM without needing the GUI at all. It works fine with vmplayer (at least on Linux, I haven't tried Windows)

e.g.:

```
 vmrun -T player start myvm.vmx nogui
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the cleanest solution, but it works: you can use `Xvfb` to run Vmplayer (but any program, really) without GUI.

First, install `Xvfb`:

```
apt-get install xvfb
sudo apt-get install x11-xkb-utils xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic x11-apps
```

After this, you can run Vmplayer without GUI:

```
Xvfb :19 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
export DISPLAY=:19
sudo vmplayer path/to/vmx &
```

The idea came from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156691/running-a-program-with-gui-without-displaying-in-ubuntu/32156776#32156776)